# Is there a good class/package for a lab notebook or journal?

Tags: document-classes, notes, journal

I would really love to get rid of my dead tree laboratory notebook and replace it with a LaTeX version. I don't want to simply use the standard sectioning commands to differentiate what I've been doing.

I'm guessing someone has been doing this already. What packages/classes have you used? What tips do you have for this?

Comment: When you move from physical to electronic be sure to archive safely and regularly (perhaps even hard copy). That's the only way your lab notebook can provide reliable evidence of what happened when.

Comment: Not sure what specifically you want. Have you seen [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/) site? There are 2 lab book templates. If nothing else, you can check the tex code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [labbook class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/labbook) on CTAN. This provides the possibility to organize lab notes for experiments in a chronologically structured order. Have a look at it to see if it suits your needs.